# How can I delete an App on Wit.ai?

Tags: wit.ai

I've created a very simple app on Wit.ai, but the App is not responding as I expect. So I want to remove it and create a new one.

But the problem is that I don't see any menu option to remove it.

How can I delete an App on Wit.ai?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting(right most)>>In danger Zone tab>>Delete App
Hope this helps.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

open your wit.ai app from the console to the right click on settings then scroll down till you find delete app